# Flutter: Specify textstyle of Button in Theme

Tags: flutter, button, styles, material-design

is it possible to influence the textStyle of a Button through the theme? In this particular case, I want every button label to have a specific fontWeight.
The `ButtonTextTheme` is only responsible for colors.

I know I can style the child of the button itself but I wanted to have the styling on theme level.
Now I'd need to create a custom Button Widget that does that for me

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes and https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-apply-style-as-a-theme-in-a-text-widget-90268328bd23

Comment: use   button:TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontFamily: 'Hind'), in TextTheme into ThemeData

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't answer my question. I want to globally influence the textStyle (weight) of Buttons - not override it in every instance